# Não consigo enviar e-mail utilizando android studio

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um formulário que será enviado por email, já criei o e-mail da gmail pra utilizar no aplicativo, já importei as bibliotecas necessárias, adicionei as permissões no Manifest, o código não apresenta erros mas também não envia o e-mail. 
[image: erro]
aqui está o layout do formulário chamado de solicitacoes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="To"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etTO"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subject"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etSubject"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Message"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMsg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send_email_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send"
    />
```

a minha activity e-mail:

```
public class Send_email extends MainActivity {

Button btnSend;
EditText To;
EditText Subject;
EditText Message;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_email);

    To = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTO);
    Subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSubject);
    Message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMsg);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email_button);


    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String to = To.getText().toString();
            String subject = Subject.getText().toString();
            String message = Message.getText().toString();

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Select Email Client"));

        }
    });
}
```

ao emular a aplicação no celular e abrir o formulário, é como se não tivesse nem rodando o código, apenas preenche os campos. Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo errado ou faltando para que o meu código funcione?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recentemente eu também estava as voltas com esse problema. Tentei de várias maneiras e todas por conta de segurança não funcionavam. Notei que teria bastante trabalho se seguisse naquela linha e existia uma maneira  bem mais fácil se seguisse o protocolo. Segue abaixo a minha resolução de acordo com o protocolo:

```
GlobalProperties gp = GlobalProperties.getInstance();
String email = "";
if (gp.getParametros().getString("EMAIL_DEFAULT") != null)
    email = gp.getParametros().getString("EMAIL_DEFAULT");

Date date = new Date();
StringBuilder msg = new  StringBuilder();

msg.append("Prezados,");
msg.append('\n' + '\n');
msg.append("  Segue em anexo base de dados " + dbname + " atualizada " );
msg.append("até a presente data ( " +  dateFormat.format(date)  + " )." + '\n' + '\n' );
msg.append("Atenciosamente,");


File sd = getActivity().getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/backups" );
String backupDBPath = "BKP_" + dbname;
File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(backupDB));
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{ email });
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Backup Diário");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , (CharSequence) msg);
try {
    startActivity( Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
       } 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
     {
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Não foi localizado software para o envio de email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

Veja que, no meu caso, pego o e-mail do destinatário nos parâmetros. Crio o corpo do e-mail via StringBuilder. Anexo ao e-mail o arquivo que esta na pasta de backups e envio pelo serviço de e-mail que o usuário escolher que esta instalado em seu celular. O remetente será o mesmo que esta cadastrado em seu dispositivo.